# Apache Spark Task not Serializable when Class exends Serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, rdd

I am consistently having errors regarding `Task not Serializable`.

I have made a small Class and it extends Serializable - which is what I believe is meant to be the case when you need values in it to be serialised.

```
class SGD(filePath : String) extends Serializable {

 val rdd = sc.textFile(filePath)
 val mappedRDD = rdd.map(x => x.split(" ")
                    .slice(0,3))
                    .map(y => Rating(y(0).toInt, y(1).toInt, y(2).toDouble))
                    .cache

 val RNG = new Random(1)
 val factorsRDD = mappedRDD(x => (x.user, (x.product, x.rating)))
                 .groupByKey
                 .mapValues(listOfItemsAndRatings => 
                                             Vector(Array.fill(2){RNG.nextDouble}))
}
```

The final line always results in a `Task not Serializable` error. What I do not understand is: the Class is Serializable; and, the Class `Random` is also Serializable according to the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/scala/util/Random.html). So, what am I doing wrong? I consistently can't get stuff like this to work; therefore, I imagine my understanding is wrong. I keep being told the Class must be Serializable... well it is and it still doesn't work!?

Comment: Is `Rating` serializable?

Comment: I can understand that you are following the scala convention to write all the functionality in a single line. But do try to split this line and write each functionality separately so that you can pin point the bottleneck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scala.util.Random` was not Serializable until [2.11.0-M2](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4664).

Most likely you are using an earlier version of Scala.

A class doesn't become Serializable until all its members are Serializable as well (or some other mechanism is provided to serialize them, e.g. `transient` or `readObject/writeObject`.)

I get the following stacktrace when running given example in spark-1.3:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.util.Random
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.util.Random, value: scala.util.Random@52bbf03d)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$SGD, name: RNG, type: class scala.util.Random)
```

One way to fix it is to take instatiation of random variable within mapValues:

```
mapValues(listOfItemsAndRatings => { val RNG = new Random(1)
                   Vector(Array.fill(2)(RNG.nextDouble)) })
```

Comment: Aha, if I recall I am using 2.10.4. That works; however, each Vector is now filled in with the same number. I need it so each Vector is a different number, or at least, most of them are different.

Comment: @monster If so, just use `Random.nextDouble` in the fill method. It takes a random seed value, so should produce different numbers.

Comment: Sadly, I need my tests to be repeatable. I found a way around it (changing `mapValues` to `map` and then using the `userid` to set the seed. Your answer helped tremendously, so thanks!

Comment: I just used `java.util.Random` as I'm stuck on Scala 2.10.6, which is serializable.